Possible issues with the Identification between $Lie(G)$ and $T_e G$ for lie group $G$
I was reading Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds and had a question regarding Theorem 8.37.
Theorem 8.37: Let $G$ be a (finite-dimension) Lie Group. The evaluation map $\varepsilon : Lie(G) \rightarrow T_e G$, given by $\varepsilon(X) = X_e$, is a vector space isomorphism. Thus, $Lie(G)$ is finite-dimensional, with dimension equal to $\mathrm{dim}(G)$.
The theorem only shows Vector space Isomorphism rather than Algebra Isomorphism. This may be a silly question, but does it always make sense to identify the Lie Algebra of G with $T_e G$? Or can there be some complications.
Is it possible that $T_e G$ can be endowed with two different brackets making it isomorphic as an algebra to two different Lie Algebras, which are not isomorphic to each other?

$T_e(G)$ can be endowed with whatever bracket you want, but the bracket we use in Lie theory is the one that makes $\varepsilon$ an isomorphism of Lie algebras, where the left-invariant vector fields are equipped with the Lie bracket of vector fields.

Is the question really asking why the tangent space $T_eG$ has the structure of a Lie algebra other than by identification with left-invariant vector fields? If so, it may be useful to say that the conjugation action of $G$ on itself fixes the identity element, and hence, via conjugation, $G$ acts on $T_eG$. The derivative of this action gives the Lie bracket on $T_eG$.

There are two different natural brackets on $T_eG$: the bracket coming from left-invariant vector fields, and the bracket coming from right-invariant vector fields. But the two brackets only differ by a sign, so they yield isomorphic Lie algebras.
